# Cant find variable : tweetsElement?

Tags: javascript

Cant find variable :  tweetsElement

I have to announce variable or what?
where is error ??

Im totaly new in Javascript

```
 <script>
        const asyncRequst = async (url) => {
            const request = await fetch(url)
            return resultBody = await request.json()
        }
        (async () => {
          try{
            const result = await asyncRequst('/tweets')
            console.log(result)
        const finalTweetStr = result.reduce((acc, element, index) => {
              console.log(index)
              console.log(element)
              return acc + `<div class='mb-4'><h1>${element.id}</h1><p>${element.content}</p></div>\n`
            }, '')
        
          tweetsElement.innerHTML = finalTweetStr;
          }
          catch(e){
            console.log('Error occured: ', e)
          }
        })()

    </script>
```

thank you in advance .

Comment: You have the code " tweetsElement.innerHTML = finalTweetStr;" - but where do you assign the initialise tweetsElement?

Comment: You are trying to define a undeclared variable. You haven't declared the `tweetsElement` anywhere and you are trying to target the innerHTML of a undefined variable.

Comment: Can you give us the HTML you are trying to target here ?

Comment: {% extends 'pages/base.html' %}

{% block head_title %}
Home    
{% endblock head_title %}
    

{% block content %}
    Welcome to <h1>T$T</h1>

    <div id = 'tweets'>
       Loading...
    </div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `element.id` to `element['id']`

and `tweetsElement.innerHTML = finalTweetStr;` to   `document.getElementById('tweets').innerHTML  = finalTweetStr;`